# How do I view a database with ruby on rails active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Working with legacy code for an assignment, was told to do a bundle exec rails db:migrate to prepare a localhost database, which worked and I'm able to run the app with data, but I want to see what the database looks like using terminal commands.

database.yml has code for sqlite3 and postgressql

Does each model have it's own database? How do I view the database?

Comment: You can use [rails dbconsole](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-dbconsole). It will bring you to the console of database. And than you can fetch your data using regular SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using sqlite3 in development and postgresql in production, which is one interpretation of your statement "database.yml has code for sqlite3 and postgresql".

In development, invoke the sql command line with `sqlite3`. Then you should get the sql command prompt. Then `.help` will give you the help menu so you can see what commands are available.

Next you'll want to open the database file, so from the sqlite3 command line, do `.open <filename>` where <filename> is whatever file is configured in database.yml.

Next you'll probably want to see the tables. So use `.tables`. From this point, you can use sql to see the contents of the tables like:

```sql
select first_name from users;
```

Or whatever you like, to see the contents.

Edit:
I just realized, by "command line" maybe you meant the Rails console? In this case invoke the rails console with `rails c` and then you can invoke ActiveRecord commands like `User.all{|u| puts u.first_name}` etc.

Comment: Just to add that running `rails db` will launch the DB client appropriate to the current environment's DB (so, `sqlite3` or `psql`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for!